# Can you infer toxicity of an ionic compound based on the toxicity of its ions in other configurations?

Tags: solutions, ions, chemical-biology, toxicity, salt

Suppose I have two ionic compounds: "Na`Y`" and "`X`Cl". If these were both 'safe' to eat, would it be true that the compound `XY` would also be 'safe' to eat, because in solution, these would dissociate into  `X+`, `Y-`, (which are also produced by our two original 'safe' compounds?).

Since safety is dose dependent, perhaps another way to ask would be whether the behaviour of the individual ions would be the same, regardless of what compound they were in prior to dissolution.

Comment: No, it doesn't work like that. Particularly because of varying solubility and/or coordination of counterion.

Answer (score 0):

It is far from an additive effect; you have to take the specific properties of the salt as a whole into account.

To cite one example: barium salts are toxic when dissolved, but relatively insoluble barium sulfate is benign enough to be ingested for examination of the digestive system. See https://medlineplus.gov/druginfo/meds/a606010.html.

Comment: Or HCl and NaOH, which produce relatively benign NaCl. Unless you're on a low salt diet...

Answer (score 0):

Generally the biological effects or functions of ions are relatively independent of the source however the total effect depends on the overall ion concentrations. This is accommodated in blood analysis by the anion gap. Your body needs certain concentrations of ions such as Na+, K+, Ca++, Mg++, etc. and anions such as Cl- and HCO3-. The proper concentrations can be arrived at by various methods within reason. It would be foolish to add K+ and Na+ by eating only NaHCO3 and KHCO3 and not eating salt. Ca And Mg are usually ingested as carbonates or organic salts. All that sodium and potassium benzoate used as preservatives contributes Na+ and K+ while the benzoate is excreted as hippuric acid. The combinations will probably not be toxic but the balance must be maintained.